# Cannot execute binary file, install driver, wlan, ath10k, firmware

Tags: firmware, binary

Im trying to install a new Firmware for my Wi-Fi device but getting error.

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

Firmware downloaded from GitHub: [ath10k-firmware-master](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware)

```
# chmod a+x firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1
# ./firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1
bash: ./firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

How to install?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions?  https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/firmware   (*you aren't supposed to execute it like you tried*)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick response.

I copy´d  and renamed the **firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1** containing in the uncompressed [ath10k-firmware-master](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware) file to:

```
cp /home/USER/Downloads/ath10k-firmware-master/QCA9377/hw1.0/WLAN.TF.2.1/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
```

and dealtet the old firmware-5.bin

```
rm firmware-5.bin
```

Then i restarted the computer and executed in the command-line: **ethtool -i wlp2s0**

```
driver: ath10k_pci
firmware-version: WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1
```

The new Firmware is loaded and working fine (no ERROR anymore in **journalctl**).

The issue i had: My internet was slowing down after a few minutes. Now everything is OK, no more slowing down.

Thank you very much!

I have one more question.

There are three different Firmware versions (14, 16, and 21).

How can i switch between Firmware versions to test what works best for me?

```
firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00014-QCARMSWP-1
firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00016-QCARMSWP-1
firmware-6.bin_WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1
```